# SQL Syntax Error via php

Tags: php, mysql, select, sum

I'm kinda new to php, this place has been a great help for me so far! Anyway, I have this code

```
$month = "
SELECT SUM(`duration`) 
FROM `connlist` AS `month_sum` 
WHERE `vatsimid` = '$vatsimid' 
AND MONTH(atc_online) = " . $pmonth . "  
AND YEAR(atc_online) = " . $year . "
";
```

That's what I get when I echo out $month

```
SELECT SUM(`duration`) 
FROM `connlist` AS `month_sum`
WHERE `vatsimid` = '1070757' 
AND MONTH(atc_online) = 07 
AND YEAR(atc_online) = 13
```

When i use this directly into phpMyAdmin, works as a charm, but when I try to do it through a php webpage, I get the syntax error. I'm using php 5.4

Thanks!

Edit: Full Code:

```
<?php
//open MySQL connection
$mysql = mysqli_connect('host', 'un', 'pass', 'table') 
or die ( "MySQL Error: ".mysqli_error() );

//Get and decode residents data
$jsonData = file_get_contents("link");
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData, true);

//Start Operations
foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value) {

//Get controller hours for today
$vatsimid = $value[vatsimid];

//Get previous month
$pmonth = date("m", strtotime("-35 days") ) ;
$pmonthName = date("M", strtotime("-35 days") ) ;
echo $pmonth;
echo $pmonthName;


//This year or last year? 
If (date("M") != "Jan") { //Checks that it's not January of the next year.
    $year = date("y");
}
else {
    $year = date("y", strtotime("-1 month") );
}

echo $year;

//Search and sum entries during last month
$month = "SELECT SUM(`duration`) 
FROM `connlist` AS `month_sum` 
WHERE `vatsimid` = '$vatsimid' 
AND MONTH(atc_online) = " . $pmonth . " 
AND YEAR(atc_online) = " . $year . "";
echo $month;
echo "</br> </br>";

$result = mysqli_query($mysql,$month);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 

$month_sum = $row['month_sum'];
echo $month_sum;

//Updates data in atclist 

$datainsert = "
UPDATE `atclist`
SET " . $monthName . "=" . $month_sum . "
WHERE vatsimid = " . $vatsimid . "";
$insert = mysqli_query($mysql,$datainsert);

if (!$insert)
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($mysql));
}  

}
/*
```

Comment: What does it display when you echo `$datainsert`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `$month_sum` variable is not set or empty in your UPDATE query.

You can add single quotes like

```
$datainsert = "
    UPDATE atclist
    SET ".$monthName."= '".$month_sum."' 
    WHERE vatsimid= '".$vatsimid."'";
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean:

```
SELECT SUM(duration) AS month_sum 
FROM connlist 
WHERE vatsimid = '1070757' AND MONTH(atc_online) = 07 AND YEAR(atc_online) = 13
```

Comment: Still doesn't work :/ By the way, error is "check ... right syntax to use near '= WHERE vatsimid = 1070757' "